# gcov error flags = 66 gcda file not generated

Tags: gcov

I am trying to run gcov for my unit test code. I passed "*-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage*"  options through CPPFLAGS and used "*-lgcov*" option through LDDFLAGS.

But, gcda files are not generated when running my program. My program exits cleanly.

```
*pathname = /unit_test/unittest/DeveloperCmds.gcda
flags = 66
pathname = /unit_test/unittest/DeveloperCmds.gcda
flags = 66
profiling:/unit_test/unittest/DeveloperCmds.gcda:Cannot open
pathname = /unit_test/unittest/AteTests.gcda flags = 66
pathname = /unit_test/unittest/AteTests.gcda flags = 66
profiling:/unit_test/unittest/AteTests.gcda:Cannot open
pathname = /unit_test/unittest/DebugTest.gcda flags = 66*
```